# Count number of keys in object with Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I would like to know how many keys are in my coffeescript object.

I can do it with this in js:

`Object.keys(obj).length`

Is there a way to do this in Coffeescript?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Object.keys(obj).length
```

It should work the same way in coffeescript

[see example](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aobj%20=%20%0A%20%20%20x:1%0A%20%20%20y:2%0A%20%20%20z:3%0A%20%20%20a:4%0A%0A%0A%0Aalert%28Object.keys%28obj%29.length%29)

Comment: Note this is only supported in Browsers that implement the ECMAScript 5 standard.  For example IE8 and earlier will choke on this.  See my example below for a coffeescript specific solution that is cross browser.

Answer (score 10):

If you are worried about legacy browser support

```
Object.keys(obj).length
```

is an ECMAScript 5 Solution

However if you are wanting to support IE8 and earlier this is a fairly unobtrusive Coffeescript specific solution

```
(k for own k of obj).length
```

This utilizes CoffeeScript's [Comprehension Syntax](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) to build an array of keys

```
keys = (k for own k of obj)  # Array of keys from obj
```

And then calls length on that array

[Example with compiled JavaScript](http://coffeescript.org/#try:obj%20%3D%20%0A%20%20%20x%3A1%0A%20%20%20y%3A2%0A%20%20%20z%3A3%0A%20%20%20a%3A4%0A%0Aalert%20(k%20for%20own%20k%20of%20obj).length)

Comment: The second code look mysterious to me. Can I have a little more explanation?

Comment: @Jokester Added some detail and links to help further understand the example.

Answer (score 0):

I create thed `keys` prototype function:

```
Object.defineProperty Object.prototype, 'keys',
    enumerable  : false,
    writable    : true,
    value: ->
        return (key for own key of @)
```

so that I can just use it like this

```
nodes_Ids: ->
  return _nodes_By_Id.keys()
```

which is used in this test

```
it 'add_Node',->
  visGraph = Vis_Graph.ctor()
  visGraph.add_Node('a' ).nodes.assert_Size_Is(1)
  visGraph.add_Node('a' ).nodes.assert_Size_Is(1)
  visGraph.add_Node(    ).nodes.assert_Size_Is(1)
  visGraph.add_Node(null).nodes.assert_Size_Is(1)
  visGraph.add_Node('b' ).nodes.assert_Size_Is(2)
  visGraph.nodes_Ids()   .assert_Contains     ('a' )
  visGraph.nodes_Ids()   .assert_Contains     ('b')
  visGraph.nodes_Ids()   .assert_Not_Contains ('c' )
```